# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8)?

Tags: math, big-o, code-analysis, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to solve a recurrence `T(n) = T(n/8) + T(n/2) + T(n/4)`.

I thought it would be a good idea to first try a recurrence tree method, and then use that as my guess for substitution method.

For the tree, since no work is being done at the non-leaves levels, I thought we could just ignore that, so I tried to come up with an upper bound on the # of leaves since that's the only thing that's relevant here.

I considered the height of the tree taking the longest path through `T(n/2)`, which yields a height of `log2(n)`. I then assume the tree is complete, with all levels filled (ie. we have `3T(n/2))`, and so we would have `3^i` nodes at each level, and so `n^(log2(3))` leaves. `T(n)` would then be `O(n^log2(3))`.

Unfortunately I think this is an unreasonable upper bound, I think I've made it a bit too high... Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: This is a problem from a problem set in my algorithm analysis text. Is it my fault this is a homework problem? I've done work above as you can see, I'm asking for help from someone that is kind enough to help. I find it rude that you downvote my question and vote to close it. This is ridiculous. Should I not post a question about quicksort analysis then because it's in every problem set for every school teaching software engineering?

Comment: @Shitikanth FYI, This question can be found in every other algorithmic texts, atleast appreciate the fact that the user is curious to know different approaches

Comment: What is (are) the base case(s) of this recurrence relation?

Answer (score 7):

One trick you can use here is rewriting the recurrence in terms of another variable.  Let's suppose that you write n = 2<sup>k</sup>.  Then the recurrence simplifies to

> T(2<sup>k</sup>) = T(2<sup>k-3</sup>) + T(2<sup>k-2</sup>) + T(2<sup>k-1</sup>).

Let's let S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>).  This means that you can rewrite this recurrence as

> S(k) = S(k-3) + S(k-2) + S(k-1).

Let's assume the base cases are S(0) = S(1) = S(2) = 1, just for simplicity.  Given this, you can then use a variety of approaches to solve this recurrence.  For example, the [annihilator method](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf) (section 5 of the link) would be great here for solving this recurrence, since it's a linear recurrence.  If you use the annihilator approach here, you get that

> S(k) - S(k - 1) - S(k - 2) - S(k - 3) = 0
>
> S(k+3) - S(k+2) - S(k+1) - S(k) = 0
>
> (E<sup>3</sup> - E<sup>2</sup> - E - 1)S(k) = 0

If you find the roots of the equation E<sup>3</sup> - E<sup>2</sup> - E - 1, then you can write the solution to the recurrence as a linear combination of those roots raised to the power of k.  In this case, it turns out that the recurrence [is similar to that for the Tribonacci numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html), and if you solve everything you'll find that the recurrence solves to something of the form O(1.83929<sup>k</sup>).

Now, since you know that 2<sup>k</sup> = n, we know that k = lg n.  Therefore, the recurrence solves to O(1.83929<sup>lg n</sup>).  Let's let a = 1.83929.  Then the solution has the form O(a<sup>lg n</sup>) = O(a<sup>(log<sub>a</sub> n) / log<sub>a</sub>2)</sup>) = O(n<sup>1/log<sub>a</sub> 2</sup>).  This works out to approximately O(n<sup>0.87914...</sup>).  Your initial upper bound of O(n<sup>lg 3</sup>) = O(n<sup>1.584962501...</sup>) is significantly weaker than this one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that link, It's far more helpful than my notes, or the textbook.

Comment: I believe the last step of templatetypedef's solution is incorrect. 1/(log base a of 2) is actually less than 1. Therefore the exponent of n should be 0.87914897.....

Comment: @user2945495- I forgot to take the reciprocal... sorry about that! Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way simpler method than proposed by @template. Apart from a Master's theorem, there is also an [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) that allows you to solve the recurrences of this kind:

[image]

which is exactly what you have. So your `g(x) = 0`, `a1 = a2 = a3 = 1` and `b1 = 1/2`, `b2 = 1/4` and `b3= 1/8`. So now you have to solve the equation: `1/2^p + 1/4^p + 1/8^p = 1`.

Solving it p is approximately `0.879`. You do not even need to solve the integral because it is equal to `0`. So your overall complexity is `O(n^0.879)`.